Raspberry Pi 5 Unable to redirect script output to file
I'm using a Pi5 to run raspotify (a service that allows you to connect spotify from another device) it also starts a script "MyScript".
I want to redirect the output from MyScript to a file but I get Permission Denied (I checked journalctl)
So in my script I have:  echo "Some Text" $A_VARIABLE >> myfile.txt
If I ls -l myfile.txt it is already set to -rw-rw-rw- pi pi
I don't know which user is running MyScript, it is launched by raspotify.
Can anyone advise why I get permission denied when I thought I'd set it so anyone can write to it?

Make sure your script is executable.

Yep it is. The script executes correctly, but the commands in the script to echo output then get the permission denied message

Who launches raspotify? You or systemd or something else?

raspotify is running as a service, so I can use systemctl status raspotify or systemctl restart raspotify to control it. These commands are run as sudo.


Double-quote the variable so that the shell doesn't try to process its value. echo "Some Text $A_VARIABLE" >> myfile.txt 2. Is the script really running in the directory you think it is?


Your redirection file specification, >>myfile.txt tries to write myfile.txt in the process's Current Working Directory, whatever that is for your raspotify service.
Try an absolute path, e.g. >>/tmp/myfile.txt, and beware of file ownership and permission  issues.

(this is really a comment, as we can only guess at the answer to your problem, however space is limited for comments)
The issue is not related to your script's permissions.
Waltinator's answer hints at a possible reason - you might have permission to write to the file but not have access to the directory where the file lives.
You didn't tell us HOW you started raspotify. If, for example, this is being run from systemd then there may be additional mandatory access controls in place. This MAY also set the runtime directory. It MAY specify a user. You can see what user raspoitfy is running from the output of `ps auxw | grep raspot' (assuming the executable is naed raspoitfy. The output of "systemctl status $SERVICE" will tell you the path to the unit file its using - the content of the unit file should have been included in your question.

Output of "systemctl status $SERVICE" shows that raspotify has unit file named librespot. Output of "ps -auxw | grep libre" shows the user as a number (62638), who is this? Both raspotify and librespot reside in folder /usr/bin. I've changed my script to write to a text file in /usr/bin and set it's permissions so everyone can write to it (chmod ogo+w). Now from journalctl I get error "Read-only file system" for that file. I'm confused?

I discovered from more research that the systemd script reaspotify is secured so it does not have access to most of the file system.
It does however get access to /var/run so by putting myfile in that location I can now rite to it as expected. Thanks all for the tips.
